# Installing package by composer require doesn't load package inside vendor folder

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I have made a new composer package in my laravel application. Then I push it to github and list in packagist. Then when I install the project by composer through 'composer require vendor/package' (sample), it doesn't load the package inside the vendor folder. But by same process I had load many packages in my Laravel applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I made the solution:
Changed package type 'metapackage' to 'library' in composer.json in my package folder. And push to github and packagist. Then installed by composer and it loaded inside vendor folder.